# Paypal Subscription Not Complete and Not Redirect to My Website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

After clicking on subscription button it redirect to paypal and after login Payment not completed. Below is my code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input name="business" value="marchent_account@paypal.com" type="hidden">
    <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
    <input name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" type="hidden">
    <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
    <input name="item_name" value="Gold Subscription Plan " type="hidden">
    <input name="item_number" value="1" type="hidden">
    <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
    <input name="currency_code" value="USD" type="hidden">
    <input name="a3" value="50.00" type="hidden">
    <input name="p3" value="1" type="hidden">
    <input name="t3" value="M" type="hidden">
    <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. 
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> -->
    <input name="cancel_return" value="https://www.mywebsite.com/status.php?action=cancel" type="hidden">
    <input name="notify_url" value="https://www.mywebsite.com/status.php?action=success" type="hidden">
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_subscribe_113x26.png" alt="Subscribe" type="image">
    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" height="1" width="1">
</form>
```

Step 1 : [image]

Step 2 : [image]

And After Login amount not Deducted and not redirect to my site.

Comment: You did not return URL that's why it is redirecting to our site. <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/payment-successful.html">